# Visual Studio Compatibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, hololens-emulator

I'm working on a HoloLens Project built on Unity (VuForia) well I downloaded the Hololens simulator and after many fixes I got it to start then it gave me final errors that diagnostic tools need to be installed so now I have installed
Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1 and downloaded Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3  (Mentioned on Hololens Required Tool Set)
so I want to ask a question should I delete/remove the old Visual Studio Enterprise Update 1 in order to install the new?

Comment: No. The updates are additive; it's perfectly fine to install update 3 on top of update 1.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try and then will update :)

Comment: It takes a year to install universal platform tools is there any offline installer?

Comment: We can't answer that here. If one is available, Microsoft's site will have it. Questions asking us to find links for you are off-topic here.

Comment: well i didn't ask for you to give me link i asked is there ? means to answer me in yes/no.

Comment: And I told you that **MIcrosoft will have that information**, which means **go to the Microsoft web site and see if they have one**., Answering yes or no means that if someone answers Yes you'll be asking for a link to it next.